# Sensible buffer size when downloading files in Java

Tags: java, performance, optimization

What is the sensible buffer size to use when transferring (irrespective of UP/DOWN) large files (3-4 gigs) with Java?

```
byte buf[] = new byte[1024]
```

or

```
byte buf[] = new byte[5 * 1024 * 1024]
```

Sometimes even if you use a large buffer and pass to a read(byte array[]) method this doesn't guarantee you that you will get a full 5 me buffer. In my tests I have observed that the average size is usually 1.5kb per read() invocation. Does this make sense performance wise? I'd be glad if someone could point me to a resource discussing the issue in greater details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you're reading from a network connection (TCP?)

1500 bytes is the default Ethernet [MTU](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/networkprotocols/g/mtu-maximum.htm), which explains why you're typically getting 1.5KB per read. The MTU can often be increased to 9KB by configuring the network stacks to use [jumbo frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame).

With this in mind, there is almost certainly no point in making `buf` larger than 9KB. Using a smaller buffer (say over 1KB) may or may not negatively impact performance.

In any case, the only way to get a definitive answer is through benchmarking various buffer sizes.

Comment: Hmz, good point. I haven't really factored in the the MTU of the TCP stack.

Comment: Using larger buffers will reduce the number of switches between Java code and native code and may have performance impact, independent of the network packet size.

Comment: Actually if you're using IPv6 you may also run into IPv6's jumbo frames and those are up to 4gb large (not that you'd use such a large frame today; though keep in mind that jumbo frames in IPv4 aren't really a standard so I'm sure you may find larger frames there as well). So I wouldn't hardcode it if that was really something to worry. Afaik Java SDK classes' IO buffers are by default 8kb large.

Comment: I have experimented the buffer size in Android device in local network. I found 1024(good/best), 4096(good) , 16384 (average). And 8k is the worst.

Answer (score 1):

In my research & testing, 8K is the optimal buffer size when reading from a socket on Linux with Java 6. If you allocate a buffer that is bigger than 8K it will simply be a waste of space. I've read that the native call Java makes uses an 8K buffer and this is why 8K is optimal but I've lose my reference. There is a bug pointing to this fact but it is not conclusive evidence: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6444633

That said, try experimenting on the platform you're interested in deploying on and you will find the optimal buffer size. If you're lazy, 8K is a great default.